# Any way to make this cUrl request using forge.request.ajax?

Tags: trigger.io

For the external API I'm using, I generally do a cUrl request like this:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 123123123123123" -X PUT -d '{"$set":{"title":"Person 1a"}}' http://domain.com/collectionapi/persons/123123123123123
```

Is there any way to port this to forge.request.ajax?  In my attempts so far, in the browser, I'm getting 500 error:

```
http://localhost:3000/_forge/proxy/moc/edakcart/
```

Response

```
{"error":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token %"}
```

My code is:

```
forge.request.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain.com/collectionapi/persons/123123123123123/',
    data: {"$set":{"title":"Person 1b"}},
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': '123123123123123'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        forge.logging.info('[trackadeApi] Updated x to '+ data.x);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        forge.logging.info('[trackadeApi] Failed to update x: '+ error.message);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that works.  Thanks to Todd https://github.com/crazytoad.

```
forge.request.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'http://domain.com/collectionapi/persons/2JMcfXZ3PJjESGGLX?auth-token=123123123',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({"$set":{
        "title": 'Person 1b'
    }}),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        forge.logging.info('[trackadeApi] Updated');
    },
    error: function(error) {
        forge.logging.info('[trackadeApi] Failed to update');
    }
});
```